# Scrollbar field (gem rails admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scrollbar, admin

I display the title on the category, I use collect, in the catalog model there are 100 lines of text, I want to create a scroll bar, I use the rails admin gem.

```
field :category_id, :enum do
    label 'Category'
    enum do
      Category.all.collect{|name| [name.title]}
    end
  end
```

this is problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAl2O.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your field how long could it go (set a height) and what to do when the y-axis is too long.

Check CSS‘s [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) on MDN.

Comment: i dont know where i can define css ?